# Do i have to escape input using mysqli_real_escape_string even though i check it using is_numeric to prevent sql injection

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

I am using `$_GET['id']` to get id and look it up in the db.

i was under impression that if i use `is_numeric` function to check the string is numeric or not then i dont have to escape the input using `mysqli_real_escape_string`. but recently found this.

> Finds whether the given variable is numeric. Numeric strings consist
>   of optional sign, any number of digits, optional decimal part and
>   optional exponential part. Thus +0123.45e6 is a valid numeric value.
>   Hexadecimal (e.g. 0xf4c3b00c), Binary (e.g. 0b10100111001), Octal
>   (e.g. 0777) notation is allowed too but only without sign, decimal and
>   exponential part.
>   ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

So my question is 
**Do i have to escape input using mysqli_real_escape_string even though i check it using is_numeric to prevent sql injection** ?

as the input will be only numeric value eg. 555, 222,456 ,879

Comment: Use prepared statements, avoid worrying about it.

Answer (score 3):

While I can't think of a specific way to attack your example, "I can't think of a way" != "It is not possible".

If you get into the habit of checking, and then passing values, eventually YOU WILL GET INTO TROUBLE!

Your statement "the input will be only numeric value eg. 555, 222,456 ,879" is obviously not true, since you've given some more complex examples in your quotation - how is SQL going to handle +0123.45e6 or 0b10? A string that contains a number is not the same as a number.

For this reason, *ALWAYS* *USE* *PREPARED* *STATEMENTS* - that way you don't have to worry about it. +1 to @Ohgodwhy.

If you could find a reason not to use prepared statements (and I don't think there is one!) then lets talk.

Comment: how about ctype_digit ?

Comment: @AMB In this specific case you could cast your value to an integer, but why would you not use a prepared statement?

Comment: @jeroen yes, prepared statemetn s are the only option as i see it, just making sure , brefore i rewrite the application. thanks